# Spark Not able to run SQL more than 64KB size

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am facing issues in running spark sql (SQL size around 85KB) on a dataset. It seems we can not have an SQL more than 64KB in spark 1.6.1 version.

I do see this issue is being fixed in Spark 2.0. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15285

My cluster is still on 1.6.1. Is it possible to get this change in my application by overriding the 1.6.1 library as a temporary work around? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please reply if any information available.